# Ubuntu18.04にGTX2070のGPUカードドライバーをインストールしたい

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu

Ubuntu18.04にGTX2070のGPUカードドライバーを以下のサイトを参考にインストールしようとしています。

[GPU カードドライバーのインストール](https://support.kagoya.jp/gput/manual/driver/index.html)

#### 発生している問題

以下のコマンドによりNVIDIAドライバーをインストールしようとしたところ、ERRORが発生しました。

```
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.14.run --silent --no-opengl-files --no-libglx-indirect --dkms
Verifying archive integrity... OK
Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 430.14..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

WARNING: Unable to find a suitable destination to install 32-bit compatibility
         libraries. Your system may not be set up for 32-bit compatibility.
         32-bit compatibility files will not be installed; if you wish to
         install them, re-run the installation and set a valid directory with
         the --compat32-libdir option.

ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 430.14 -k
       4.15.0-50-generic`: 
       Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

       Building module:
       cleaning build area...
       'make' -j8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.15.0-50-generic
       IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH='' modules...(bad exit status: 2)
       ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 430.14 not found
       Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-50-generic
       (x86_64)
       Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.14/build/make.log for more
       information.

ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was
       installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS
       logs for more information.

ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
       '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions
       on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux
       driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

'/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'の内容は以下でした。

```
$ cat /var/log/nvidia-installer.log 
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sun May 26 09:36:54 2019
installer version: 430.14

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer
    --no-opengl-files
    --no-libglx-indirect
    --dkms

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 430.14.
-> There appears to already be a driver installed on your system (version: 430.14).  As part of installing this driver (version: 430.14), the existing driver will be uninstalled.  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: Yes)
WARNING: Unable to find a suitable destination to install 32-bit compatibility libraries. Your system may not be set up for 32-bit compatibility. 32-bit compatibility files will not be installed; if you wish to install them, re-run the installation and set a valid directory with the --compat32-libdir option.
-> Uninstalling the previous installation with /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall.
-> Searching for conflicting files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64' (430.14):
   executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Installing DKMS kernel module:
ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 430.14 -k 4.15.0-50-generic`: 
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.15.0-50-generic IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH='' modules...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 430.14 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-50-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.14/build/make.log for more information.
-> error.
ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more information.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

#### 試したこと

関連したものの再インストールは行いました。

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
$ sudo apt-get remove cuda-*
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

カーネルのバージョンは以下です。

```
$ uname -a
Linux xf 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gccのバージョンは以下です。

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

お手数をおかけしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ホビー用途でGTX1060(ドライババージョン410)を使っていました。16.04の頃より18.04はトラブルが多く有った記憶があります…

---

少し古いですが次のリンクに Ubuntu Japanese Team Member の方の書かれた記事があります。

- [第454回　Ubuntu 16.04 LTSにNVIDIA製ドライバーをインストールする3つの方法：Ubuntu Weekly Recipe｜gihyo.jp … 技術評論社](https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/ubuntu-recipe/0454)

3種類のインストール方法がある、と書かれています。

> - Ubuntuの公式リポジトリからパッケージとしてインストールする方法
> - Graphics Drivers TeamのPPAからパッケージとしてインストールする方法
> - NVIDIAのサイトからダウンロードしてインストールする方法

それぞれの特徴はリンク先を見ていただきたいのですが、質問文中で行おうとしているのは3つめの方法になりますが、最新バージョンのドライバを利用したい、というだけであれば2つめの[PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)を利用する方法も選択肢に入るかと思います。

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-430
```

の2コマンドでインストールできるので楽です。

---

3つめの方法をどうしても採る必要がある場合も、2つめのソース(オリジナルからの変更内容)が参考になるかもしれません。

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list` ファイル中の行

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

を有効化(コメントアウトを解除)した上で次のコマンドを実行すれば取得できます。

```
apt-get source --download-only nvidia-graphics-drivers-430
```